# Problem with pagebreak in titlepage

Tags: page-breaking, titlesec

I am trying to make a first page template. At this template I want a box at the bottom of the page with some text, but I can not get TeX to put it at the bottom, but rather it is moved to the next page. I have no clue why. A MWE is:
TeX-document:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{test}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{test}
\usepackage{showframe}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle text}
\documenttype{Doc type}
\documentnumber{Doc no.}
\prepared{Author}
\approvedby{}
\revision{whatever}
\securityclass{something}
\date{\yyyymmdddate\today}
\releaseyear{2014}
\releasemonth{June}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text
\end{document}
```

Style-document:

```
\ProvidesPackage{test}[2015/04/10 V 1]
\typeout{Using test style.}

\RequirePackage[small,sf,bf]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{ %
    \setlength{\textheight}{30cm}
    \setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-3pt}
    \setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
    \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
    \vspace{2.2cm minus 1cm} %
    \begin{center} %
        {\ifdef{\MyTitle}{\MakeUppercase{{\MyTitle}}}{}}\vspace{0.5cm} %
        \vspace{-9mm} %
        {\ifdef{\subTitle}{\MakeUppercase{{\subTitle}}}{}} \\ %

        \vspace{20cm} %

        \framebox{ % I WANT THIS BOX ON THE SAME PAGE
        \begin{tabular}{c} %
            \fontsize{3.5mm}{1.2em}\selectfont %
            \ifdef{\Revision}{Revision \Revision .}{}\\ %
            \ifdef{\releaseMonth}{\releaseMonth}{} \ifdef{\releaseYear}{\releaseYear}{}\\[7mm] %
            \ifdef{\DocumentNumber}{Document No. \DocumentNumber}{}\\[7mm] %
            \fontsize{2.5mm}{1.2em}\selectfont %
            \copyright\hspace{.25em} \ifdef{\releaseYear}{\releaseYear}{} %
        \end{tabular} %
        }
    \end{center} %
    \newpage %
} %

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

And the class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2015/04/10 V 2.0 by me]

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\documenttype}[1]{%
\newcommand{\DocumentType}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\documentnumber}[1]{%
\newcommand{\DocumentNumber}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\prepared}[1]{%
\author{#1}
\newcommand{\Prepared}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\approvedby}[1]{%
\newcommand{\ApprovedBy}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\revision}[1]{%
\newcommand{\Revision}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\securityclass}[1]{%
%}
\newcommand{\SecurityClass}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\releaseyear}[1]{%
\newcommand{\releaseYear}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\releasemonth}[1]{%
\newcommand{\releaseMonth}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{ %
\newcommand{\subTitle}{#1}%
} %

\usepackage{xstring}

% Declare requirements
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage[]{unicode-math} % For proper handling of fonts in math mode.
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}

% Pass unknown options to the base class.
\DeclareOption*{%
\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}

\ProcessOptions \relax
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

\endinput
```

Now the problem is that the box marked with "I WANT THIS BOX ON THE SAME PAGE" to be on the same page, but it have to be quite high up on the page to stay there. If I decrease the `\vspace` it will stay on the same page, but I want it at the bottom. What can be the error??

Comment: do you intend `\framebox{ % ` rather than ` \framebox{% ` (it outs a space before the tabular inside the box?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Why don't you make a small selfcontained example instead of expecting other to install a cls for tests? Beside this your page layouts changes in `\maketitle` are too late. Use `\enlargethispage` .

Comment: note that `\maketitle` (nor anything else in general)  should never be changing document global settings such as `\textheight`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to change

```
    \vspace{20pt} %
```

to

```
    \vspace{\fill}%
```

Note that you should not use `inputenc` as you are using xetex or luatex.

[image]

Comment: \vfill will make the box end up on the right page, but not at the bottom.

Comment: @Robert it is right at the bottom of the text area see the picture I just added, it is immediately above the page number which is in the footer _below_ the text block. If that is not what you mean, yolu need to clarify your question.

Comment: ok, I want it at the bottom of the page. That is my problem. I do not understand what to modify to make it appear closer to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Robert Your page layout is completely skewed as you have changed the document-global settings within the document, so you need to fix that first. But do you mean you want it below the page number? If so you need to add it in the page foot, not in the page body. (or at least it is more natural to do that)

Comment: I want both the page number and the stuff in the box to appear closer to the page bottom. The page extends several cm after the page number. I am sure I have made some mistakes with modifying the document-global settings. I am no expert at all in this, what are you referring to that I need to fix?

Comment: @Robert remove all the length settings at start of `\maketitle` normally you'd drop the page number so I'd use `\thispagestyle{empty}\enlargethispage{3cm}` and then the `\vspace{\fill}` will go 3cm lower.